# C# Getting the src from a iframe html tag?

Tags: c#, regex, iframe

Basically I have a string which the user creates and it may or may not have a iframe link for youtube in. Since this is a client application it doesn't use html tags and I have a special form that shows things like youtube videos. However, I need to get the src from the tag and replace all the data around it with nothing. 
It may also have multiple links so this needs to be something like regex to do it globally..

Example:
User string:

```
<iframe width='300px' height='225px' src='http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/4FhG-UYRHJ0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What I want to be outputted:
I want the users to just see: `http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/4FhG-UYRHJ0` then I can handle the rest.

Any help is much appreciated as I have no idea how to even start with this. Thankyou all.

Comment: With [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) you can do it

Comment: you should try to do it yourself, it is a really simple regex. This site is meant to help with problems, not to do your work for you.

Comment: I'm currently learning 7 languages, each one of them fairly different from the others. Regex would just confuse me at this point. Also why try reinvent the wheel? If someone has already done it they're attempt will most likely be better than mine.

Comment: Hi user1763295, if you are learning 7 languages regex would be of even more benefit - you're going to have a very powerful tool that you can take with you as you move between languages. I started learning about regex here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also use this

```
string iframe = "<iframe width='300px' height='225px' src='http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/4FhG-UYRHJ0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";

            Match matchdec = Regex.Match(iframe, @"\ssrc='\b(\S*)\b", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (matchdec.Success) 
            {
                if (matchdec.Groups.Count > 1)
                {
                    string retval = matchdec.Groups[1].Value;
                }
            }
```

for all match you can use:-

```
string iframe = "<iframe width='300px' height='225px' src='http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/4FhG-UYRHJ0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
                iframe += "<iframe width='300px' height='225px' src='http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/newid' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";

                Match matchdec = Regex.Match(iframe, @"\ssrc='\b(\S*)\b", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                while (matchdec.Success)
                {
                    if (matchdec.Groups.Count > 1)
                    {
                        string retval = matchdec.Groups[1].Value;
                    }
                    matchdec = matchdec.NextMatch();
                }
```

To Replace add this line

```
iframe = Regex.Replace(iframe, retval, "yournewurl");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This says unrecognised escape sequence when I put the regex in?

Comment: Ignore the above, I forgot the @. Thanks a lot this regex worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regular expression to get you started:

```
(?<=src=')[^']+
```

Note: May be some edge cases that aren't accounted for. I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be picking the src actually out but it is picking up every instance of src.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bellow code;

```
var source = Regex.Match(iframeStr, "<iframe.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```